# Identifying errors in Release build of Android application

Tags: android, proguard

I've recently started studying the build flavors of the Android application and the Proguard. So what I'm doing now is creating a release build of my application. For this, following are the changes I've made in buildTypes of my build.gradle file.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.chitchatReleaseConfig
    }
}
```

I've created a proguard-rules.pro file for the release build by referring the following link as mentioned at various places.

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples

However, I'm still confused as to what types of files in my project apart from the general files I should actually include in the proguard-rules.pro. Because obviously due to the release build, at certain points in my app, I keep getting the FileNotFoundException and I'm not able to debug it.

So how do I decide what files in my project I should include in my proguard-rules.pro and how do I debug FileNotFoundException in my app in the release build?

Comment: Hi Sarthak Grover,if you want know your application Log info,you can look [https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard comes with certain problems but it works great for minifying the apk size. I will suggest that if you are using third party libraries in your app then use their proguard-rules as well in proguard-rules file.

To get error from signed apk use [Fabric Crashlytic](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install). Its easy to integrate(10 minute max) and it will show the complete stacktrace of exception on your fabric console .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    SignNAME {
        keyAlias 'yourKeyAliasName'
        keyPassword 'yourKeyAliasPassword'
        storeFile file('F:/ANDROID KEYSTORES/myKeystore.jks') // Give the Path of your Keystore here
        storePassword 'yourStorePassword'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 24        // change depending upon your requirement
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3" // change depending upon your requirement
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourPackageName.yourAppName"
    minSdkVersion 18       // change depending upon your requirement
    targetSdkVersion 24    // change depending upon your requirement
    versionCode 1          // change depending upon your requirement
    versionName "1.0"      // change depending upon your requirement
    multiDexEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.SignNAME
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
```

After this, in *Android Studio* above Bottom-Left Corner you will find `Build Variants`. Click it and change `Build Variants` from `debug` to `release`. Wait until gradle builds. And you are all set to `Run`.

Comment: I really wouldn't suggest putting your signing information in your gradle files.  Because that's going to be checked into source control.  Which means anyone with source control will have access to your signing key, which is a bad idea.

Comment: So, how'd you suggest to do it `Gabe`? Bcoz, this always works for me.

Comment: If you're a 1 man show that's doing hobby programs, its fine.  If you want to make a business out of it, you don't want that key ever leaking.  For a small company it should stay on your laptop and a physical backup device at an offsite location (home, safety deposit box etc) and the passwords entered at build time.  For a company that key should be accessible only to the 1 or 2 people who make the release builds.  Or even better, it should be on a server that only the manager or lead dev has access to, and release build done via build command (and a remote backup device somewhere, or course).

Answer (score 0):

Fabric Crashlytic will be best. I am using it and able to track crashes in the release build version wise.